# Kendo UI - cannot find grid after first load

Tags: javascript, user-interface, grid, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI Grid. It has a change event that fires fine the first time.  It calls a js function as follows:

```
function showTaskWindow(arg)
{
    var grid = $("#TaskItemGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var taskURL;
    var taskTitle;
    grid.select().each(function ()
    {
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this));
        taskURL = dataItem.TaskURL;
        taskTitle = dataItem.Folio;

    })
    $('#taskpane').load(taskURL);
```

}

the new view loads fine.  However if I select another row in the grid, the function fires but it cannot find the "taskitemgrid" grid.  undefined.  Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: The more information you provide the easier will be for someone to help you. Source from which your function is called and error details could be useful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! by "undefined" you mean that you get that as an error or as a query result? More details on what exactly you get might help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could reproduce this in a jsFiddle or jsBin it would help us figure out what is happening.

My best guess is that `#taskpane` is a Kendo Window widget, and you have it set to not use an iframe, but the content that you load from `taskURL` is a full HTML page with a  tag and everything, and has another  tag that re-imports jQuery. That could possibly change the whole context of jQuery to the window contents. You might want to set the Window widget to use an iframe (there is a setting to enable that behavior somewhere).

This is just a guess though... I could be completely wrong. If you can include more code, it would help a lot.